# imagecolorallocate(): Red component is out of range

Tags: php, gd

I have a issue with PHP 7.4.5 and GD. I have an image manipulation script and sometime I get this error:

> imagecolorallocate(): Red component is out of range

Anybody has an idea how to avoid this?

```
$image = imagecreatetruecolor($calcWidth, $calcHeight);
for ($y = 0; $y < $height; ++$y) {
       for ($x = 0; $x < $width; ++$x) {
            [$r, $g, $b] = $pixels[$y][$x];
            $allocate = imagecolorallocate($image, $r, $g, $b);
            imagesetpixel($image, $x, $y, $allocate);
        }
  }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What could cause a "color index out of range" error for imagecolorsforindex()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3874533/what-could-cause-a-color-index-out-of-range-error-for-imagecolorsforindex)

Comment: Yes, this is the only answer I found in the whole web about this error. But it did not help, since I have no transparent images.

Comment: Even without Transparency, this answer should help .. Since using `imagecolorstotal()` should give you a way to detect if your total colors is within range?

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it with this condition, because sometimes an r/g/b value was 256 and rgb can only have up to 255:

```
[$r, $g, $b] = $pixels[$y][$x];
if($r > 255) { $r = 255; }
if($g > 255) { $g = 255; }
if($b > 255) { $b = 255; }
if($r < 0) { $r = 0; }
if($g < 0) { $g = 0; }
if($b < 0) { $b = 0; }
```